# What is wrong about this application of Kirchhoffs Current Law?

Tags: current, circuit-analysis, kirchhoffs-laws

At a recent exam I had this very simple problem concerning Kirchhoffs Laws:
[image: problem statement]

I am concerned with problem *c*

Now my understanding of this is:

I can combine both nodes, and since all currents in the node need to cancel out, \$i_c\$ should be 2A. Now my professor marked this problem as wrong and told me it should be 8A instead.

Am I doing something fundamentally wrong here?

**Update:**
The professor reviewed the answer sheet because some other answers were wrong and did not mention the 8A again, and accepted the solution ‍♂️

Comment: Have you taken into account the direction of the arrow with the -1A ?

Comment: Unless I'm missing something I think you're correct with 2A. 0 = -(-1)-(Ic)+(4)-(3) -> Ic = 1+4-3 -> Ic = 2. Did your prof explain how he got 8A?

Comment: The only easy way I get 8A for Ic is by changing the sign or direction on the 3A.

Comment: I like to write the equation with outflowing currents on the left and inflowing currents on the right. These must be equal to each other. In (c), I'd write: \$-1\:\text{A}+3\:\text{A}+i_c=4\:\text{A}\$ and then solve that for \$i_c=2\$. I've no idea what your professor is doing.

Comment: I also must be blind because for me 2A is the correct answer. Or maybe it should be -3A?

Comment: In fact, (b) and (c) are the same circuit with the same currents, just with the sign and magnitudes mixed around a little - but the end result is that they're exactly the same. (b)'s (-3A) flowing in = (c)'s (3A) flowing out.(b)'s (1A) flowing in = (c)'s (-1A) flowing out. The solution for (b) is Ib = -4A, which = (c)'s (4A) flowing in, which leaves (b)'s (2A) flowing out = (c)'s Ic.

Comment: I also think the answer for (a) is Ib=5A, (b) is Ib=-4A and (c) is Ib=2A. Your professor has made a mistake somewhere. You should ask for an explanation as to why you were marked incorrect. Maybe they have made a mistake in the marking scheme.

Comment: how did you obtain the image? If this is what was on the questio. then professor is wrong but if the arrow 3A would flip he would be right. Maybe its sloppy drawing?

Comment: The image is a screen cap of the question sheet, which was given out beforehand for students to solve at home and bring to the exam.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Professor is wrong. The correct answer is 2A. I solved it algebraically just as every one else, 4=3+Ic+-1, Ic = 2. A DC simulation in Spice yields 2A as as well.

Comment: Which version of Spice did you use, and what did the model look like?

Answer (score 9):

I agree, it should be 2A. I don't know how it could be 8A

[image]

Comment: Easily: reverse the 3A current direction and you're about to get 4A+3A-(-1A).